# Как можно узнать о попытках или использовании протокола NFC на Android?

Tags: android, android-sdk, безопасность, nfc

Есть устройство Android с NFC 
На устройстве установлено приложение, которое работает с меткой, например какой-либо банковский клиент

Можно ли как-то узнать стороннему приложению или системе о попытках обращения к метке? 
Есть ли некий сигнализатор использования?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33761705/how-to-read-write-nfc-card-in-different-activities возможно здесь есть ответ на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 3):

При обращении к *NFC* метке, у андроида запускается `Intent Filter` на `ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED`, `ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED` и `ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED`. Они отсылаются по всей ОС и каждая программа или сервис, которые могут их обрабатывать будут их отлавливать и обрабатывать (в фоновом режиме).

Исходя из этого, можно создать свое приложение или/и сервис, которые будут ловить данные Intent'ы и показывать, что был перехвачен. Следовательно, если ваше приложение поймало данный Intent, то и другие приложение на данном телефоне работающие с NFC тоже перехватили его.

Только для реализации придется попотеть: нужно будет разобраться с `Intent Filter`, с фоновой работой приложения или сервиса. А для начала можно почитать вот это (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html)